# React typescript Error type is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure why is there problem with State type.

```
import React from 'react'

type State = { err: boolean | Error }
const newError = new Error('ss')

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { err: newError }
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(info)

    this.setState({ err: error })
  }

  render() {
     return <p>{this.state.err.message}</p>
  }
}
```

I've got error:

> TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'true | Error'.
>   Property 'message' does not exist on type 'true'.

Comment: What's unclear? You typed the state.err as boolean or Error, and *only one of those has a message property*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh! I'm dumb :( thanks

Comment: it's should be: false | Error